# Template generates an error for no reason

Tags: twig

I just faced an error. It is working fine the same install in other place

> Call to undefined method
> __TwigTemplate_ffcada2905c270c1bb8149ef10195d5fdfc3992f37169ff72fca2cffa2148cdf::checkSecurity()

File: ./vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/CoreExtension.php

What can cause it? On other pages it works fine

Comment: Issue about this was opened [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/3411)

Comment: Thanks, i will keep an eye to it, seems to be the same issue, as i'm not using sandbox extension.

Comment: Yes, will be best idea, don't think a solution will follow here. Seems someone already bumped the topic over there. Just add an answer here when the issue got solved with a link

Answer (score 0):

For me the quick solution was to load the sanbox extension

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/api.html#sandbox-extension